# Facebook Graph API - fql is deprecated for versions v2.1 and higher

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know there will be a similar question on stackoverflow but it does not seems to work in my case.

Here is my code :

```
public function fetchFriendDetails($accessToken, $userId) { // echo $accessToken; exit;
        $curlUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/fql?access_token=' . $accessToken . '&pretty=0&q={' . urlencode('"v_1":"select uid,name,birthday_date,username,current_location from user where uid in (select uid1 from friend where uid2=me()) order by birthday_date desc"') . '}';

        $ch = curl_init($curlUrl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $intermediate = Util::convertJsonString($output, 'uid', '\,', ',');
        return Util::convertJsonString($intermediate, 'id', '\,', ',');
    }
```

It gives me following output :

```
{"error":{"message":"(#12) fql is deprecated for versions v2.1 and higher","type":"OAuthException","code":12}}
```

I know it is deprecated https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog but can anyone please help me what should I change in my above code so that it will return accurate result ?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You need to specifically request a version below 2.1

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/fql?access_token=`

Also if the token you are using was issued via a v2.1 application it will not work no matter what you try.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I know that it won't work but what should I do to run retrieve the result form this query - `select uid,name,birthday_date,username,current_location from user where uid in (select uid1 from friend where uid2=me()) order by birthday_date desc`

Comment: @RakeshShetty you cannot retrieve a full list of friends using v2.0 and above see changelog.https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: This doesn't help, i tried adding v2.0 and still get fql is deprecated for versions v2.1 and higher

Comment: @StepanYakovenko your app is obviously set as 2.1 and above. Seeing that this is from 2014, I cannot imagine many apps running 2.0